# Disable Port blocking on linux

Tags: linux, centos, port

I have shut down iptables for my server, inspite of that when I check on http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it says my ports are not open.
Where do I have to specify to open ports. I am running a linux server

Answer (score 0):

Is your server/PC behind a NAT router? If so, you may need to port forward the required ports to your server/PC. A helpful website for guides on how to do so (as it depends on your router model) is http://portforward.com/

If your server is not behind a NAT router or if you've verified you're port forwarding, is the application that's supposed to be listening on the specific port even running? Try this:

```
netstat -anp | grep <port number>
```

Netstat manual page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

If you can't find the port as listening on netstat, make sure that the application is running.

Comment: Its a web application trying to create a scoket to another server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server program (daemon) running on a machine listening on a port for that port to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the 'nmap' package on your server with 'yum install nmap -y' and check listening ports on your server:

```
nmap localhost
```

If you can see your port listening then you need to check your router for proper port forwarding, else you need to make sure that your application is working and listening for the port.

For the example, Apache2 will listen for port 80 by default.